# Cannot use HTMLUnit Webdriver from Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

I'm trying to use the HTMLUnit WebDriver from Python with the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    webdriver = WebDriver('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
    webdriver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

... and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bcc_mon_webdriver.py", line 8, in <module>
    webdriver = WebDriver('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 105, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=ANY, browserName=htmlunit, version=}' ; Stacktrace: Method process threw an error in RequestHandler.java
```

I use `selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar` with the Python `selenium` module also in version 2.25.  The Selenium server is running on localhost and it works fine with e.g. `DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX`.

Do I have to install htmlunit manually? The selenium websites says that the standalone-jar contains all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't have a node that matches the `{platform=ANY, browserName=htmlunit, version=}` pattern. To fix it you need to start a selenium node with those browser settings, like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=htmlunit
```

On the Selenium wiki ( http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 ) it says:

> "By default, this starts 11 browsers : 5 Firefox, 5 Chrome, 1 Internet
>   Explorer."

So to be able to use different browsers - like `htmlunit` - you'll have to start nodes with -browser parameter, check `desired_capabilities.py` file (located in your selenium egg under selenium/webdriver/common/) for a reference of which parameters are required for each browser.